# Returning a GZipped response using Spring Cloud Gateway gets stuck

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

I'm using Spring Cloud Gateway to forward requests to a back-end service. Since some of our back-end services send out their results gzipped, defining a Global Filter to unzip before processing in the routes and gzip again before it's send out to the client seems a good idea. This way there's no need to do it for every route. Using the various ideas that are around on Stack Overflow led to the following definition to gzip the result of the processing steps.

```java
@Component
public class GlobalGZipFilter implements GlobalFilter, Ordered {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalGZipFilter.class);

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return -2; 
    }



    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {

        ServerHttpResponse originalResponse = exchange.getResponse();

        DataBufferFactory bufferFactory = originalResponse.bufferFactory();
        ServerHttpResponseDecorator decoratedResponse = new ServerHttpResponseDecorator(originalResponse) {

            @Override
            public Mono<Void> writeWith(Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> body) {
                log.info("Content should be GZipped: {}", isGZipped(originalResponse));
                if (isGZipped(originalResponse) && body instanceof Flux) {
                    Flux<? extends DataBuffer> flux = (Flux<? extends DataBuffer>) body;

                    return super.writeWith(flux.buffer().map(dataBuffers -> {
                        ByteOutputStream outputStream = new ByteOutputStream();
                        for (DataBuffer i : dataBuffers) {
                            byte[] array = new byte[i.readableByteCount()];
                            i.read(array);
                            outputStream.write(array);
                        }

                        String resultResponse = new String(outputStream.getBytes());

                        return bufferFactory.wrap(zipString(resultResponse));
                    }));
                }

                return super.writeWith(body); // if body is not a flux. never got there.
            }
        };

        return chain
                .filter(exchange
                        .mutate()
                        .response(decoratedResponse)
                        .build()); // replace response with decorator
    }
```

The flow is to gather the buffers that contain the result, convert it to one complete `byte[]` and compress this `byte[]` using gzip.

The result seems to be properly processed, but only after the application has been stopped the result shows up in the client. Somehow the transaction doesn't end before closing. Is there something needed to confirm the result or is the current chosen flow just incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

The problems is not so much in the handling of the flux or the data. What I forgot to consider is that when gzipping the content to be returned, the length of the reply will be different. Adding a content length on basis of the gzipped content will do the trick:

```
  String resultResponse = new String(outputStream.getBytes());
                        byte[] zippedResponse = zipString(resultResponse);

                        originalResponse.getHeaders().setContentLength(zippedResponse.length);

                        return bufferFactory.wrap(zippedResponse);
```